# Setting up an additional logger in Rails – how to instantiate only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In addition to the default Rails logger, I'd like to create my own one. I will be using [LogstashLogger](https://github.com/dwbutler/logstash-logger), configured with a custom URL.

I created a file `lib/custom_logstash_logger.rb` with:

```rb
class CustomLogstashLogger
  include ActiveSupport::Configurable
  config_accessor :logstash_url

  def self.log(message)
    # ?
  end
end
```

And I'm configuring it via `config/initializers/custom_logstash_logger.rb`:

```rb
CustomLogstashLogger.config.logstash_url = ENV.fetch("LOGSTASH_URL", nil)
```

Now, I could go ahead and define `self.log` such that I always create a new logger whenever the method is called:

```
def self.log(message)
    logger = LogStashLogger.new(uri: self.config.logstash_url)
    logger.info(message)
end
```

But that is hardly efficient—the logger is instantiated every time the `log` method is called.

What would be the ideal way to instantiate the `LogStashLogger` already when the class is configured, and not when the logger is used? I don't want to modify `application.rb` or set a global variable that holds the logger—it should be a class method.

Comment: Use lazily instantiated instance variable `@logger ||= LogStashLogger.new(uri: self.config.logstash_url)`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Do you want to post that as an answer? It works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Aleksei Matuishkin, one can use a lazily instantiated variable:

```rb
@logger ||= LogStashLogger.new(uri: self.config.logstash_url)
```

This allows creating the logger when first calling `log`.